# Access Value of a Pointer to a swift struct(Swift String) in objective-c from swift

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c

I have a void pointer to a swift string in objective-c like so. `void * = ....swift string` and I have a helper method In swift as such `@objc public func swiftTest(pointer:UnsafeRawPointer){ //body }` and I want to basically pass in that void pointer to that method and access the value of the swift string.

I was also tested this with NSStrings and Swift Bridged Strings. What I managed to get working was `@objc public func swiftTest(pointer:UnsafeRawPointer){ let mySelf = Unmanaged<AnyObject>.fromOpaque(pointer).takeUnretainedValue() }` Now that code above can give me access to the NSString object or Bridged Swift string but I cannot use that for a Swift.String since it is struct and  requires it be a class.

This is the way I need it to work, I know I could go about doing this differently but I need it to work with pointers. Thanks for any help

Comment: Is the pointer pointing to an `NSString` or a `Swift.String`? If it is really the case that "that code above can give me access to the NSString object", then the pointer is pointing to a `NSString`, not a `Swift.String`, and you can't force it to point to a `Swift.String`.

Comment: No, I Meant that I was testing with a NSString and that is what ended up working. I need a similar solution to work for a Swift string. I passed in a NSString just to test out and found a solution to work. But now I need to make it for the Swift string. Which is the main Goal I wanted to accomplish

Comment: Try `pointer.load(as: String.self)` then.

Comment: I have already tried that along with many other things, it will not work. I need the unretained value just like the piece of code in the second half, unfortunately that will not work for swift strings since they are structs.

Comment: What do you mean by "it will not work"? Swift strings have value semantics so "unretained" doesn't really make sense in this context. I'm assuming you have some other code that doesn't work if you use `load(as:)`? Can you show that other code, i.e. a [mcve]?

Comment: the reason i have to do that is because the pointer i have is a C pointer.